# PHP replacing character in string

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

I tried to change character 'ç' with 'c' in a string using preg_replace() function. This segment of my code where i am trying to do it.

```
                 echo $mystr;  // The output of it is : çanakkale
                 $pattern = array("'ç'");
                 $replace = array('c'); 
                 $mystr = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $mystr);
                 echo $mystr;
```

This code works when i add before this line before the first line:

```
                 $mystr = "çanakkale";
```

However when I get this string from Database this code has no effect on it.
How can I fix it? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your method seems to work fine: http://codepad.org/ykGhxFPd

Comment: Then why it gives **same** output?

Comment: Why do not use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) in your case. To my mind, Perform a regular expression with  [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) is useless / heavy to use just to replace only one letter. Anyway it won't solve your problem...

Comment: I gonna convert string of array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer there is nothing wrong with that code segment. But the reason why it doesnt changes anything is the charset of my database is **ISO 8859-9**. Mapping this charset to **UTF-8** will solve this.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no need to use arrays here.
2. Also, you have put an extra set of quotes inside your `$pattern`, which is causing the match to fail.
3. Your pattern needs delimiters `/`.

   ```
      $mystr=  'çanakkale';
      $pattern = '/ç/';
      $replace = 'c'; 
      $mystr = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $mystr);
      echo $mystr;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `u` modifier:

```
$mystr = preg_replace('/ç/u', 'c', $mystr);
```